# how to PiecewiseExpand BSplineBasis to get Basis matrices of uniform B-splines presented in the paper?

Tags: splines

As we all know, the definition of B-spline contains the B-spline basis function, which has the recursive form
[image]

$B_{j,k}$ is the j-th degree $k-1$ polynomial. It has nonzeros only in interval $[t_j,t_{j+k})$ which contains $k$ spans $[t_j,t_{j+1}),...,[t_{j+k-1},t_{j+k})$.
So for the span $[t_{i},t_{i+1})$ there are in total $k$ degree $k-1$ polynomials. I want to extract the coefficients of every power. These coefficients form a matrix called $M^k(i)$, whose first column number is the coefficients of the first nonzero polynomial $B_{i-k+1,k}$, like this picture:
[image]

The result for $M^4(i)$ when $t_{i+1}-t_{i}=1$ given in [General Matrix Representations for B-Splines](https://xiaoxingchen.github.io/2020/03/02/bspline_in_so3/general_matrix_representation_for_bsplines.pdf),
4.1 Basis matrices of uniform B-splines,
is as follows:

[image]

In 4.2 Basis matrices for Bezier curves, the matrix is

[image]

```
colth = 0; 
PiecewiseExpand[BSplineBasis[{3, {0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1}}, colth, x]] 
(*gives the colth column of Basis matrices for Bezier curves *)
```

How could I get the basis matrices of uniform B-Splines?

Comment: What have you tried so far? As opposed to just linking to a paper and not asking/hoping that someone will read through it all and give you the result that you are looking for, can you, please, give a bit more background information on this topic? It is not at all clear to me how these matrices relate to the curves in question.

Comment: @CATrevillian I have edited it. Is it ok to reopen ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'll answer the second one first, since that is relatively straightforward:

The easiest way to get that matrix is

```
Transpose[Table[CoefficientList[PiecewiseExpand[BernsteinBasis[3, k, x], 0 < x < 1], x],
                {k, 0, 3}]]
   {{1, 0, 0, 0}, {-3, 3, 0, 0}, {3, -6, 3, 0}, {-1, 3, -3, 1}}
```

which uses the Bernstein basis for Bézier curves. The equivalent B-spline formulation is

```
Transpose[Table[CoefficientList[PiecewiseExpand[BSplineBasis[{3, {0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1}}, k, x],
                                                0 < x < 1], x], {k, 0, 3}]]
```

(exercise: why?)

---

With that, getting the first matrix only necessitates a change in the knot sequence used. I'll leave as an exercise figuring out where the knot sequence I am using below came from:

```
Transpose[Table[CoefficientList[
     PiecewiseExpand[BSplineBasis[{3, {-3, -2, -1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4}}, k, x], 0 < x < 1], x],
     {k, 0, 3}]]
   {{1/6, 2/3, 1/6, 0}, {-1/2, 0, 1/2, 0}, {1/2, -1, 1/2, 0}, {-1/6, 1/2, -1/2, 1/6}}
```

Comment: I have no idea why do so? the paper only requires that $t_{i+1}-t_{i}=1$ ? {-3, -2, -1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4} why start with -3?  and the first 4  are not the same,  the last 4 element are not the same ? It seems different form some books . I have another quesion [how many control points need to interpolation ?](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/40617) could you recommend me some material or papaer ?

Comment: "why start with -3" - I encourage you to experiment with other knot sequences that satisfy the condition you already stated, and look at what happens to the polynomial expressions generated by `PiecewiseExpand[]`. As for references, I would recommend Farin's "Curves and Surfaces for Computer-Aided Geometric Design" as a starting point.